# Find location and normal of a plane based on the relative intersection points from 3 lines

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

Here is an illustration of the problem

[image: 3D Illustration of the problem]

I have 3 points in a 3d space, in my example the points are: `(0, 0, 0)`, `(26, 0, 0)` and `(13, 27, 0)`

I then have a plane with 3 holes in it, with positions relative to the center of the plane, positions of those points are: `(-0.5, -0.25, 0)`, `(-0.1, -0.5, 0)`, `(-0.2, 0.5, 0)` and a point located 1 unit above the plane *(so the relative position of this point to the plane is `(0, 0, 1)` )*

The size of the plane is `1 x 1` if it were layed down on the x/y plane in the 3d space.

How can I find where in 3d space the center point of the plane is located, and the normal of the plane; such that lines can be drawn from all the 3 points through the holes in the plane and intersect at the point above the plane.

If this were in real life I could hold a piece of paper up to my eye and move it around until the 3 holes in the paper line up with the 3 points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Not sure to understand what are the real constraints and the relaxable constraints ; when you say in your last sentence : like  "holding a piece of paper up to my eye and move it around until the 3 holes in the paper line up with the 3 points." do you mean by controlling that my eye is in point $(0,0,1) $, and I think this is not possible in general, or do you mean that any point at distance 1 will do ?

Comment: Yes I mean that eye is at a fixed point of (0, 0, 1).  I guess with your eye it's not really possible; so maybe a bad example.

Comment: I appreciate the humor. In fact, I was wrong. It is possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have three points $P_1, P_2, P_3$ whose coordinates are specified in world coordinates.  We also have a plane with a coordinate system $F$ attached to it, with unknown origin and unknown orientation. In addition, we have three points (holes) on the plane $q_1, q_2, q_3$ specified in the coordinate system attached to the plane. And finally we have a certain point $e_1 $ specified in the coordinate system attached to the plane.

The relation between the world coordinates and the coordinates in frame $F$ is

$ p = R q + d $

where $p$ is the vector in world coordinates, $q$ is the same vector but with coordinates expressed in frame $F$.  Matrix $R$ is a rotation matrix and $d$ is the position of the origin of frame $F$ expressed in world coordinates.

From point $e_1$ to the three points $q_1, q_2, q_3$ we can draw three rays, and we want $P_1$ to lie on the ray $\vec{e_1 q_1}$ and $P_2$ to lie on the ray $e_1 q_2$ and $P_3$ to lie on the ray $\vec{e_1 q_3} $.  The distances $a = \overline{P_1P_2}, b = \overline{P_1 P_3}, c = \overline{P_2 P_3} $ are the sides of $\triangle P_1 P_2 P_3 $

Hence, we can write

$ p_1 = e_1 + t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} $

$ p_2 = e_1 + t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2 } $

$ p_3 = e_1 + t_3 \vec{e_1 q_3 } $

where $p_1 , p_2, p_3 $ are the points $P_1, P_2, P_3 $ but expressed in frame $F$.

Now we can write

$a^2 = ( t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} - t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} ) \cdot ( t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} - t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} )$

$ b^2 =  ( t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} - t_3 \vec{e_1 q_3} ) \cdot ( t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} - t_3 \vec{e_1 q_3} )$

$ c^2 =  ( t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} - t_3 \vec{e_1 q_3} ) \cdot ( t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} - t_3 \vec{e_1 q_3} )$

which is a quadratic system of three equations in three unknowns, and can be solved numerically, for $t_1, t_2, t_3 $.

Once $t_1, t_2, t_3$ are found, then $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are known.  But

$p_1 = R^T (P_1 - d) $

$p_2 = R^T (P_2 - d) $

$p_3 = R^T (P_3 - d) $

Taking the differences

$p_1 - p_2 = R^T (P_1 - P_2)$

$p_1 - p_3 = R^T (P_1 - P_3)$

thus eliminating $d$.  Now we can solve for $R$, because we know that

$(p_1 - p_2) \times (p_1 - p_3) = R^T \left( (P_1-P_2) \times (P_1 - P_3) \right)$

Therefore, we can now write

$ \begin{bmatrix} (P_1 - P_2) && (P_1 - P_3) && (P_1 - P_2) \times (P_1 - P_3) \end{bmatrix} = R \begin{bmatrix} (p_1 - p_2) && (p_1 - p_3) && (p_1 - p_2) \times (p_1 - p_3) \end{bmatrix} $

and we can solve for $R$ by matrix inversion.

Once $R$ is known we can solve for $d$ from (for example)

$P_1 = R p_1 + d $

or any of the other two equations involving $P_2, p_2$ or $P_3, p_3$.

Now the plane and the frame ($F$) attached to it are completely specified.

Now some numerical results.  I will go through the steps to find a solution.

$\underline{\text{Step 1}}$:  Find $\vec{e_1 q_1} , \vec{e_1 q_2 } , \vec{e_1 q_3 } $

$\vec{e_1 q_1} = q_1 - e_1 = (-0.5, -0.25, -1) $

$\vec{e_1 q_2} = q_2 - e_2 = (-0.1, -0.5, -1)$

$ \vec{e_1 q_3} = q_3 - e_1 = (-0.2, 0.5, -1) $

$\underline{\text{Step 2}}$: Find a,b,c

$ a = \overline{P_1 P_2} = 26 $

$ b = \overline{P_1 P_3} = \sqrt{898} $

$ c = \overline{P_2 P_3} = \sqrt{898} $

$\underline{\text{Step 3}}$: Write down the quadratic system in the parameters $t_1, t_2, t_3$, for example, the first such equation is

$a^2 = ( t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} - t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} ) \cdot ( t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} - t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} )$

Expanding the right hand side, this becomes

$ a^2 = t_1^2 \left( \vec{e_1 q_1}\cdot\vec{e_1 q_1} \right) + t_2^2 \left( \vec{e_1 q_2} \cdot \vec{e_1 q_2} \right) - 2 t_1 t_2 \left( \vec{e_1 q_1} \cdot \vec{e_1 q_2} \right) $

And we have

$\vec{e_1 q_1}\cdot\vec{e_1 q_1} = (-0.5)^2 + (-0.25)^2 + (-1)^2 = 1.3125 $

$\vec{e_1 q_2} \cdot \vec{e_1 q_2} = (-0.1)^2 + (-0.5)^2 +(-1)^2 = 1.26$

$\vec{e_1 q_1} \cdot \vec{e_1 q_2} = (-0.5)(-0.1) + (-0.25)(-0.5) + (-1)(-1) = 1.175 $

which completely specifies the first equation.  The second and third equations can be built similarly.

Next, we have to solve these equations.  And for that, we can use the multivariate Newton-Raphson method, or you can use an app such as this WolframAlpha [Widget](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e6bfd79be503e98ee35900cc07b0d5eb)

$\underline{\text{Step 4}}$:  From the solver, we get four solutions, let's take one of them:  $t_1 = 6.137053, t_2 = 28.74539, t_3 = 30.70222$

Using these values for the $t$'s, we can compute the $p's$

$p_1 = e_1 + t_1 \vec{e_1 q_1} = (0, 0, 1) + 6.137053 (-0.5, -0.25, -1) = ( -3.06853, -1.53426 , -5.137053 ) $

$p_2 = e_1 + t_2 \vec{e_1 q_2} = (0, 0, 1) + 28.74539 (-0.1, -0.5, -1) = (-2.87454, -14.372695 , -27.74539 ) $

$ p_3 = e_1 + t_3 \vec{e_1 q_3} = (0, 0, 1) + 30.70222 (-0.2, 0.5, -1)
= (-6.140444, 15.35111, -29.70222) $

$\underline{\text{Step 5}}$:  Compute $(P_1 - P_2), (P_1 - P_3) $ and $(p_1 - p_2)$ , (p_1 - p_3) $

$P_1 - P_2 = (-26, 0, 0) $

$P_1 - P_3 = (-13, -27, 0 ) $

$p_1 - p_2 = (-0.19399, 12.838435, 22.608337) $

$p_1 - p_3 = (3.071914,-16.88537,24.565167)$

Next, compute

$(P_1 - P_2) \times (P_1 - P_3) = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} && \mathbf{j} && \mathbf{k} \\ -26 && 0 && 0 \\ -13 && -27 && 0 \end{vmatrix}  = (0, 0, 702) $

and

$(p_1 - p_2) \times (p_1 - p_3) = \begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} && \mathbf{j} && \mathbf{k} \\ -0.19399&& 12.838435&&22.608337 \\ 3.071914 && -16.88537&&24.565167 \end{vmatrix}  = ( 697.128435 , 74.21626  , -36.16297  ) $

And define the $A$ matrix as follows

$A = \begin{bmatrix} P_1 - P_2 && P_1 - P_3 && (P_1 - P_2) \times (P_1 - P_3 \end{bmatrix} $

That is,

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} -26 && -13 && 0 \\ 0 && -27 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 702 \end{bmatrix} $

and define matrix $B$ to be

$ B = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 - p_2 && p_1 - p_3 && (p_1 - p_2) \times (p_1 - p_3) \end{bmatrix} $

so that,

$B = \begin{bmatrix}  -0.19399 && 3.071914 && 697.128435 \\ 12.838435 && -16.88537 && 74.21626 \\ 22.608337 && 24.565167 && -36.16297 \end{bmatrix}$

Now we have

$ A = R B $

so

$ R = A B^{-1} $

Inverting $B$ we get

$ B^{-1} = 10^{-3} \begin{bmatrix} -2.46043 && 34.97571 && 24.34895 \\ 4.346926 && - 31.967889 && 18.190676 \\ 1.414616 && 0.1506 && -0.073382 \end{bmatrix} $

Hence,

$R = A B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.0074611 && -0.493786 && -0.8695515 \\ -0.117367 && 0.863133 && -0.491148 \\
0.99306071 && 0.1057212 && -0.051514 \end{bmatrix} $

$\underline{\text{Step 6}}$:  Now we want to compute the world coordinates of the origin of the frame $F$ that is attached to the plane, which is vector $d$.  We have

$ P_1 = R p_1 + d $

from which

$ d = P_1 - R p_1 = (-5.20164, -1.55892, 2.94481 ) $

And finally the eye world coordinates are

$ E = d + R e_1 = (-6.07119, -2.05007, 2.893291)$

These are all the steps.

Finally, here is a summary of the results for the $4$ solutions of the triple $(t_1, t_2, t_3)$ that the solver found, and their corresponding $R, d$ and $E$.  The first one is the one we explained in detail.

I. $ t_1 = 6.137053, t_2 = 28.74539, t_3 = 30.70222$

These values result in

$R = \begin{bmatrix} 0.00746105 && -0.493785883 && -0.869551514 \\ -0.117367085 && 0.863132973 && -0.491148083 \\ 0.993060572 && 0.105721207 && -0.051514331 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} d = \begin{bmatrix} -5.20164 \\ -1.55892 \\ 2.944805 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} E = \begin{bmatrix} -6.07119 \\ -2.05007 \\ 2.893291 \end{bmatrix} $

II. $t_1 = -39.1468, t_2 = -19.9873, t_3 = -33.1025 $

with these values, we get

$R = \begin{bmatrix} -0.675949507 && 0.007959405 && -0.736904955 \\ -0.154280656 && -0.979311947 && 0.130941165 \\ -0.720617613 && 0.202199796 && 0.66319341 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} d = \begin{bmatrix} 42.73715 \\ 7.347167 \\ -14.499 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} E = \begin{bmatrix} 42.00024 \\ 7.478108 \\ -13.8358 \end{bmatrix}$

III. $t_1 = -6.13705, t_2 = -28.7454, t_3 = -30.7022 $

These result in

$R = \begin{bmatrix} -0.00746105 && 0.493785883 && 0.869551514 \\ 0.117367085 && -0.863132973 && 0.491148083 \\ 0.993060572 && 0.105721207 && -0.051514331 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} d = \begin{bmatrix} -6.94074 \\ -2.54122 \\ -2.84178 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} E = \begin{bmatrix} -6.07119 \\ -2.05007 \\ -2.89329 \end{bmatrix}$

IV. $ t_1 = 39.14684 , t_2 = 19.98731, t_3 = 33.10248$

The corresponding $R, d, E$ are

$R = \begin{bmatrix} 0.675949507 && -0.007959405 && 0.736904955 \\ 0.154280656 && 0.979311947 && -0.130941165 \\ -0.720617613 && 0.202199796 && 0.66319341 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} d = \begin{bmatrix} 41.26334 \\ 7.60905 \\ 13.17265 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{25pt} E = \begin{bmatrix} 42.00024 \\ 7.478108 \\ 13.83584 \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Thanks for your extremely complete answer; the trouble is I'm lacking a basic understanding of maths, so am struggling to see how you got to your t1, R, d, E results.  Would it be possible to break down one of your four solutions even further  (ie starting from the point values).  Assuming I know nothing more than +-/* is it possible to break down your work?  I know the answer will be very long, but I think other noobs like me might find it useful in the future.

Comment: What you're asking could take me several hours.  I am afraid that's not possible.

Comment: On a second thought.  I will try to break down the solution as you requested.  Just give me some time.

Comment: @DavidB I've written the detailed steps of how to obtain $R, d, E$ for one of four possible set of the parameters $t_1, t_2, t_3$.  If there is anything more you'd like explained, I'll more than happy to provide further details.

Comment: I am not fully satisfied of the re-writing of my solution. I like yours, based on linear algebra (can it be slightly simplified ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the complement.  I don't think the math involving linear algebra can be simplified further.  I provided details for the OP upon their request, and I think, although it added to the length of the solution, it puts everything in perspective.

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea thanks.  This is the most legendary level of details I've ever seen in a stackexchange answer!  Really appreciate the time it took to put this together.

Comment: @DavidB You're welcome.  I enjoyed solving this very interesting problem.

Comment: @Calm down and have some tea
Please, have a look at the "Remark 1" I just added to my answer with the corresponding figure. The fact that I find 5 solutions (and you 4) is almost certainly due to a case of figure. I think the most important here is the characterization through spindle torii intersections.

Comment: I don't believe there are more than $4$ solutions, because our formulations are ultimately equivalent.  Did you actually find $5$ solutions.  Does the MATLAB code in Appendix B in your solution provide all the possible solutions ?  And if it does, does it list $5$ solutions ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, the Matlab program, in fact, due to some restrictions I have added, provides a unique solution. Besides, have you noted that your solutions I and III, and II and IV are very similar (due to symmetries) ?

Comment: Yes.  I've noted that.

Comment: But they are still distinct solutions.

Comment: Now my program gives the same four solutions as yours.

Comment: Great.  I'm thrilled that our solutions match.

Comment: I'm stuck between steps 3 and 4.  I used your example to get the equations for b2, and c2 such that the 3 equations are (t1, t2, t3 changed to x, y, z for ease of reading):
`
676 = (x^2)1.3125 + (y^2)1.26 - (2xy)1.175
898 = (x^2)1.3125 + (z^2)1.29 - (2xz)0.975
898 = (y^2)1.26 + (z^2)1.29 - (2yz)0.77
`

I put this into wolframalpha widget but it will not give me any solutions.  I've also tried to put it into python: https://pastebin.com/eDZhLSZ3

I have literally spent like 8 hours doing this about 30 times from scratch and cannot get it right...what am I missing?

Comment: @DavidB Yes.  I tried the widget and I found that it is not working.  I don't know why.  But you can use the original Wolframalpha.com site to solve the three equations as follows:  Enter : "solve {1.3125 x^2 + 1.26 y^2 - 2.35 x y = 676 , 1.3125 x^2 + 1.29 z^2 - 1.95 xz = 898, 1.26 y^2 + 1.29 z^2 - 1.54 yz = 898}" in the command line.  I tried that and it worked.

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea i have managed to reproduce your results finally (using `nsolve` in python sympy)!  However when I try plugging in some "real world" example data I do not get what i would consider "sensible" results.  Maybe I am misunderstanding what `E` and `d` represent.  Is `d` the world coordinates of the origin of the plane, and `E` is the world coordinates of the eye?  I just can't seem to make sense of the results I get.  (ie they position the eye and plane in total weird places)

Comment: Yes, vector $d$ is the origin of the coordinate frame attached to the plane (according to which you specify the "relative" coordinates of the holes) and $E$ is the world coordinate position vector of the point when the three lines intersect.

Answer (score 1):

(see figure below).

Let $A(0,0,0)$, $B(13,27,0)$ and $C(26,0,0)$ and $E$ the (unknown) position of the eye. Let $A',B',C'$ be the holes and $E'$ the point $(0,0,1)$ (with relative coordinates). Let us call $\Pi'$ the pyramid with triangular base $A'B'C'$ and apex $E'$.

Your issue amounts to find pyramid(s) $\Pi=(ABC)E$ with fixed triangular basis $ABC$ and a certain apex $E$ (where your eye will be situated) with given angles

$$\angle AEB, \ \ \ \angle BEC, \ \ \ \angle CEA\tag{1}$$

these given angles being the corresponding angles of the little pyramid $\Pi'=(A'B'C')E'$ whose cosines can be at once computed.

The knowledge of (1) is equivalent to the knowledge of

$$\begin{cases}\cos \angle AEB&=&0.603963367,\\
\cos \angle BEC&=&0.749307543,\\
\cos \angle CEA&=&0.913698555.\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

where the numerical values on the right are the cosines of the corresponding angles of the little pyramid (see Appendix A).

An image: having $E,A,A'$, aligned, the same for $E,B,B'$, and for $E,C,C'$ is equivalent to say that one can "chop" pyramid $\Pi$ by a certain plane and get $\Pi'$ as the remaining part.

[image]

*Fig. 1.*

I have obtained four solutions $E=(x_E,y_E,z_E)$, by using a Matlab program (see Appendix B)

**Appendix A:** The cosine of an angle such as $\angle AEB$ (which will have to be identical to the cosine of  $\angle A'E'B'$) is obtained by the following formula :

$$\cos \angle AEB = \frac{\vec{EA}.\vec{EB}}{\|\vec{EA}\|\|\vec{EB}\|}\tag{3}$$

(dot product divided by product of norms) which can be written, if $E$ has coordinates $(x,y,z)$ (where $c$ is the first cosine in relationship (2)):

$$\frac{(0-x)(13-x)+(0-y)(17-y)+(0-z)^2}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)((13-x)^2+(17-y)^2+(z)^2)}}=c \tag{4}$$

Writing in the same way two other equations for the two other constraints, one gets a system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns that is in general impossible to solve by hand but not difficult to solve using specialized software. This what I have done by writing the following program:

**Appendix B:** Matlab program with symbolic variables $x,y,z$:

```
 % First part: getting the angles of the
 % little pyramid with vertices A',B',C',E'
 % with "local" coordinates.
 P1=[-0.1,-0.5,0
     -0.2,0.5,0
     -0.5,-0.25,0
      0,0,1]; 
 for k=1:3;
    E=P1(4,:);
    U=P1(k,:)-E;V=P1(mod(k,3)+1,:)-E;
    c=(U(1)*V(1)+U(2)*V(2)+U(3)*V(3))/(norm(U)*norm(V));
  end;

 % Second part: with the results of the first part : 
 c1=0.603963367;c2=0.749307543;c3=0.913698555;
 syms x y z
 [X,Y,Z]=solve(...
 (x*(x - 13) + y*(y - 27) + z^2)^2==...
 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*((x - 13)^2 + (y - 27)^2 + z^2)*c2^2,...
 ((x - 13)*(x - 26) + y*(y - 27)+z^2)^2==...
 ((x - 26)^2 + y^2 + z^2)*((x - 13)^2 + (y - 27)^2 + z^2)*c1^2,...
 (x*(x - 26)+y^2 + z^2)^2==...
 (x^2 +y^2 + z^2)*((x - 26)^2 + y^2 + z^2)*c3^2,x,y,z);
 E=[];
 % Elimination of spurious solutions:
 for k=1:length(X)
    if imag(X(k))==0 && imag(Y(k))==0 && imag(Z(k))==0
       E=[E;[X(k),Y(k),Z(k)]],
    end
 end;
 E
```

Giving the following results :

giving as its result the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of four possible points $E$ :
$$\begin{array}{rrr}
-6.071186942 & -2.050072661 & 2.89329071\\
42.000242986 & 7.478108432 & 13.8358443\\
-6.071186941 & -2.050072661 &-2.89329071\\
42.000242986 & 7.478108432 & -13.8358443 \end{array}$$

which are in full conformity with the results of @calm down and have some tea. (please note that the third and the fourth points are symmetrical of the first and second points with respect to horizontal plane, a result that could have been expected).

**Remark 1:** this conformity has been made possible by changing the order of the association between the holes and the points: note that in the program above, we have $c_2,c_1,c_3$ instead of the order $c_1,c_2,c_3$ that I had considered at first.

**Remark 2:** Here is a geometrical explanation of the non-unicity of the solution. An important fact is that the set of points under which a line segment, for example $AB$, is seen under a certain angle is

- in 2D the union of two circular arcs delimitated by $AB$ and
- in 3D, [spindle torii](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpindleTorus.html) with traces in the horizontal plane represented in the figure below.

With the notations of the figure below [Please note that we designate an arc of circle by the point which is onto it], the triads of spindle torii that will have common intersection points are:

$$C_1 \cap C'_2 \cap C'_3, \ \ C'_1 \cap C_2 \cap C'_3, \ \ C'_1 \cap C_2 \cap C'_3, \ \ C'_1 \cap C'_2 \cap C_3, \ \ C'_1 \cap C'_2 \cap C'_3$$

which makes $5$ intersections for this figure (or $10$ is we had to consider points $E$ below the horizontal plane...).

[image]

*Fig. 2: Let us consider for example $C_1 \cup C'_1$ which is the locus of points of the horizontal plane under which one sees line segment $AB$ under a same angle. It is the 2D trace of the corresponding 3D locus, the spindle torus obtained by rotating the 2D locus about $AB$.*

Comment: Just added a complete result with a "general purpose" program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I notice that your solution for point E does not match any of the solutions that `@Calm down and have some tea` came up with using the same point values.  Is one of you wrong, or are you calculating different things?

Comment: @David B I just noticed an error. I am going to fixed it.

Comment: I am now in perfect agreement with the first solution $(-6.07119, -2.05007, 2.89329)$ of @Calm down and have some tea. I am going to give some more details.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks :)

Comment: @JeanMarie I really appreciate your answer.  I've marked Calm down and have some tea as "The Answer"; but you one was good too

Answer (score 1):

Let the points in the dark grey plane be denoted $(a_x,a_y,a_z),~(b_x,b_y,b_z),~(c_x,c_y,c_z)$. Let the points in the light grey plane be denoted $(d'_x,d'_y,d'_z),~(e'_x,e'_y,e'_z),~(f'_x,f'_y,f'_z)$. Note, however, that the $d',e',f'$ points are given in a different coordinate system corresponding to the small light grey plane, that is rotated and translated away from the coordinate system given by the large dark grey plane. Let's say that the point $\vec{d}\,\!'$ can be denoted by $\vec{d}=(d_x,d_y,d_z)$ in the latter coordinate system (which I will take as the more 'natural' or 'desirable' set of coordinates to work with). Similarly for points $e'$ and $f'$.

Now, suppose that the centre of the small light grey plane is given by $\vec{g}=(g_x,g_y,g_z)$. Then the coordinate transformation from the dark to the light plane is given by multiplying by a rotation matrix, say $\overleftrightarrow{R}$, and then adding a translation by $\vec{g}$. So, we have $\vec{d}\,\!'=\overleftrightarrow{R}\vec{d} +\vec{g}$. What we already know is $d'$ and we want to find $d$, so we note that $d=R^{-1}(d'-g)$. Similarly for $f$ and $g$. This also works to find the 'eye', which in the light grey's coordinate system is $\hat{z}'=(0,0,1)$ and can be converted to the dar grey plane's coordinate system similarly (let's denote it $z$).

Now write down the equation of a line between $a$ and $d$ and demand that $z$ lies on it. Repeat with $b$ and $e$, and with $c$ and $f$. You should get a bunch of equations that you can use to solve for $R$ and $g$, which are what you want. In particular, the normal to the light grey plane should be the third column of $R$.